# Shopping Cart Promotional Labels

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

If a product is part of a shopping cart promotional rule e.g. BUY 3 FOR THE PRICE OF 2, I would like to display this label on the product view page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy solution.  I can offer 3 options.

1. add a new block at each product page.  This block will add the current product to the cart, validate it and find applicable rule ids. Then remove the current product from the cart and display the labels of the rules. Not easy, not fast, but very flexible.
2. For each rule add a new tab with "Applied Products", like in admin > catalog > catagories > edit category > category products.  It assumes the module adds a new table with the product-to-rule link.  Than again, at the product page find rules by this new table (fast) and display labels.  Downside you have to select products.
3. If the condition is very simple, like list of the products SKUs, your custom module can do LIKE %sku% search by serialized rule conditions.